Why TextField in jetpack compose is causing unnecessary recompositions?
I'm attempting to utilize TextFields in my Jetpack Compose project. Instead of individually coding each TextField, I opted to employ forEach{} on a list of TextField data to generate them dynamically. However, I'm encountering an issue where typing in one TextField triggers recomposition of others, sometimes even those unrelated. Occasionally, the label of a TextField recomposes repeatedly, up to 10-20 times. I'm puzzled by this behavior. Below is the composable code snippet I'm using for TextFields.
@Composable
private fun TextFields(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ManualMeasurementViewModel,
    selectedLandType: LandTypes
) {
    val textFieldFormat = remember {
        Regex("^(?!0)(?!.*\\.\\..*|\\.$)\\d{0,5}(\\.\\d{0,4})?\$")
    }

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .heightIn(max = 600.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        userScrollEnabled = false,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
    ) {
        measurementFields.take(selectedLandType.landShapeFaces).forEach { textField ->
            item {
                RoundedIconTextField(
                    label = textField.label,
                    value = when (textField.side) {
                        MeasurementFields.SIDE_A -> {
                            viewModel.sideA
                        }

                        MeasurementFields.SIDE_B -> {
                            viewModel.sideB
                        }
                    },
                    onValueChange = { value ->
                        if (value.isEmpty() || textFieldFormat.matches(value)) {
                            when (textField.side) {
                                MeasurementFields.SIDE_A -> {
                                    viewModel.updateSideA(value)
                                    if (viewModel.sideAHasLocalError) viewModel.updateSideAHasLocalError(
                                        false
                                    )
                                }

                                MeasurementFields.SIDE_B -> {
                                    viewModel.updateSideB(value)
                                    if (viewModel.sideBHasLocalError) viewModel.updateSideBHasLocalError(
                                        false
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

